# Bad notification in startForeground: contentIntent required error on Android 2.3.4

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

I have a `Service` that I am wanting to use the `startForeground()` function in:

```
public void putServiceToForeground() {
    if (notif == null) {

        notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setContentTitle("Location Updates Service")
         .setContentText("Getting Location Updates")
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setTicker(getText(R.string.location_service_starting))
         .build();
    }
    startForeground(notificationID, notif);
}

public void removeServiceFromForeground() {
    if (notif != null && mNotificationManager != null) {
        notif.tickerText = getText(R.string.location_service_stopping);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notif);
    }
    stopForeground(true);
}
```

I am starting and stopping this in the `onConnected()` and `onDisconnected()` methods of my `Service`.

In newer `Android` versions everything is fine, and I get no errors, but in 2.3.4 I get the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=com.mycomp.app id=678567400 
notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x40)
```

After reading on SO about this, I assume I need to provide a `contentIntent` for when a user taps the notification? Is this normal to set within my `Service`? Couldn't I just return the user to my main `Activity`?

Answer (score 4):

> I assume I need to provide a contentIntent for when a user taps the notification?

Apparently yes. I cannot remember trying showing a `Notification` sans `contentIntent`, but that certainly seems to be what the error is suggesting.

> Is this normal to set within my Service?

Usually, you provide a `contentIntent` to allow the user to act upon the `Notification`. In the case of `startForegound()`, it should direct the user someplace where they can control the behavior of the service (e.g., to stop the music player service).

> Couldn't I just return the user to my main Activity?

Whatever floats your boat and makes your users happy, not necessarily in order of importance.

Comment: I would just want to return my user back to the main `Activity` of my app, which is where they could stop location updates. How do I even reference my `Activity` from my `Service`?

Comment: @NicHubbard: "How do I even reference my Activity from my Service? " -- you don't "reference [your] Activity", at least not in how I would use the term "reference". You create a `PendingIntent` that will lead the user back to that activity. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html and http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to start your Activity or go to *any* Activity from a Service. In general, you shouldn't try to start an Activity unless you call startActivity or startActivityForResult to go from one Activity to another. In addition, you shouldn't try to start another Activity unless the user asks to start it. You don't want to push users around without allowing them to control their workflow; it's a UX model that will cause users to hate you.

That's why notifications and PendingIntents are there. When something in your Service requires user attention, post a notification. When the user is ready to handle the situation, he or she can click the notification to go back to an Activity in your app. If the user is in the middle of some other task when you post the notification, you allow the user the chance to finish the work.

startForeground() is used to put a Service into a "high" priority, where the system will avoid stopping it. It's used to run services such as music players, where the user wants the Service to keep running in most circumstances. A notification is required for startForeground(), because the rules are that you can't run a foreground service without somehow notifying the user with a persistent message.
In the past, some developers got around this notification requirement with a trick: they provided a notification without an icon. The system doesn't display notifications that don't have icons, so the foreground service was "hidden" from the user. This hole has been filled; if you try to do this with a notification supplied to startForeground(), the system will supply an icon for you.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that I should not go to an Activity from a Service. I was just confused about how to use an Intent in the Notification that is used for startForeground().